# CPU or Graphics card defect?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, bios, pci-express, post

From time to time my computer dies while in usage. The screen either turns completly white, black or shows thin vertical stripes in two colors. I then have to kill it with the power button.

When I then try to start it again it sometimes works. But sometimes it gets stuck at the POST-Code **b2**: Legacy Option ROM initialization. I have to take out the BIOS battery and take it in later again to make it work.

However, when I switch the PCIe-Slot, I do not get error **b2** anymore. I then get error **d6**: No console output devices found and 5 beeps. This is very strange because it seems like the Graphics card does not get recognized in any x16 PCIe-Slot. It only gets recognized in x8 PCIe-Slots. And according to the AMI beep codes, 5 beeps mean there is a problem with the **CPU**. So what is defect now? The CPU or the Graphics card?

**Addition**: I just got the idea that maybe the fan of the card might be broken. Because when I play games the card stays pretty silent. When it then crashes and I restart, the fans directly run to maximum speed and stay there there for about 15 seconds and then slow down again. So maybe the card is overheating and then dying?

Comment: My vote is for a bad graphics card.

Comment: But why would I then have to reset the bios to make it work again?

Comment: Because the card is defective.